# How can I make AI Platform deployed model publicly accessible?

Tags: google-cloud-ml

I have created a model and deployed it to Cloud AI Platform Predictions (ML Engine).

How can I make the REST end-point publicly accessible? Right now, it is visible only within my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a policy.yaml with the following contents:

```
bindings:
- members:
  - group:allAuthenticatedUsers
  role: roles/ml.modelUser
```

Then, set the IAM policy of the model:

```
gcloud ai-platform models set-iam-policy my_model --project=my_project policy.yaml
```

You can use the same method to restrict to a specific Google Group of users from a specific domain

```
bindings:
- members:
  - group:admins@example.com
  - domain:example.com
  role: roles/ml.modelUser
- members:
  - user:sean@example.com
  role: roles/ml.modelUser
```